# Running jar as a service problem

Tags: 16.04, command-line, java, services, jar

after a few days of pondering around google I give up.

Running Tika-Server with command line works fine and Tika-Server starts responding on http://localhost:9998:

```
java -jar tika-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Following [this guide](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/ubuntu-16-java-service-wrapper-example) (with appropriate changes to scripts, paths and jar names ofc) Tika-Server is not responding on http://localhost:9998. I have used option with logging from this guide (at the bottom) and output to log file is the same as is when Tika-Server is run with command line.

Service does not show up with command

```
systemctl | grep running
```

but it shows up with command

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled
```

as enabled.

I have also tried to run java service via init.d path, but it didnt work.

What am I missing?

Comment: What does `systemctl status the-name-of-your-service` print? e.g. `systemctl status Tika-Server` if you set up your service as `/etc/systemd/system/Tika-Server.service`

Comment: It returns alot, not sure which part you are interested in. This is interesting part: ● Tika-Server.service - Tika Server Java Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/Tika-Server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2018-03-22 08:33:28 UTC; 50min ago
  Process: 3993 ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/Tika-Server.sh stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3991 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/Tika-Server.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2797 (code=exited, status=143)

Comment: Hmm, after running sudo systemctl start Tika-Server.service command again, it appears it started working.. Could there be a timeout problem or something?

Comment: I think this indicates the server itself failed/exited at some point after being started. Logs would help. Instead of having `Type=forking` and `ExecStart`, `ExecStop`, `ExecReload` point to a script that starts/stops/restarts the java jar, try putting the java jar command directly in the .service file, e.g. `Type=simple` then `ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /path/to/Tika-Server.jar` and remove `ExecStop` and `ExecReload` -- systemd (`systemctl status ...`) then will also show you logs (anything printed by the server on stdout/stderr), which the intermediate script is redirecting to /dev/null

Comment: Awesome, will try this for sure!!